# Recursively create hierarchical hash from Mongo collection in Ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion, hash, tree, hierarchical-data

I am trying to create a hash that looks like this:

```
{"difficulty"=>{"easy"=>{}, "normal"=>{}, "hard"=>{}}, "terrain"=>{"snow"=>{"sleet"=>{}, "powder"=>{}}, "jungle"=>{}, "city"=>{}}}
```

From a MongoDB collection which is and enumerable list of hashes that looks like this:

```
{
"_id" : "globalSettings",
"groups" : [
    "difficulty",
    "terrain"
],
"parent" : null,
"settings" : {
    "maxEnemyCount" : 10,
    "maxDamageInflicted" : 45,
    "enemyHealthPoints" : 40,
    "maxEnemySpeed" : 25,
    "maxPlayerSpeed" : 32,
    "lightShader" : "diffuse",
    "fogDepth" : 12,
    "terrainModifier" : 9
}
},
{
"_id" : "difficulty",
"groups" : [
    "easy",
    "normal",
    "hard"
],
"parent" : "globalSettings",
"settings" : {

}
}
{
"_id" : "terrain",
"groups" : [
    "snow",
    "jungle",
    "city"
],
"parent" : "globalSettings",
"settings" : {
}
}
{
"_id" : "snow",
"groups" : [
    "sleet",
    "powder"
],
"parent" : "terrain",
"settings" : {
    "fogDepth" : 4
}
}
{
"_id" : "jungle",
"groups" : [ ],
"parent" : "terrain",
"settings" : {
    "terrainModifier" : 6
}
}
{
"_id" : "city",
"groups" : [ ],
"parent" : "terrain",
"settings" : {
    "lightShader" : "bumpedDiffuse"
}
}
{
"_id" : "easy",
"groups" : [ ],
"parent" : "difficulty",
"settings" : {
    "maxEnemyCount" : 5
}
}
{
"_id" : "normal",
"groups" : [ ],
"parent" : "difficulty",
"settings" : {

}
}
{
"_id" : "hard",
"groups" : [ ],
"parent" : "difficulty",
"settings" : {
    "maxEnemyCount" : 20
}
}
{
"_id" : "sleet",
"groups" : [ ],
"parent" : "snow",
"settings" : {
    "fogDepth" : 2
}
}
{
"_id" : "powder",
"groups" : [ ],
"parent" : "snow",
"settings" : {
    "terrainModifier" : 2
}
}
```

Every time I try to write the function, I get stuck when setting the parent of the group.  How do I recurse, yet keep track of the path of hierarchy?

The closest I've come is with this:

```
def dbCurse(nodes, parent = nil)
  withParent, withoutParent = nodes.partition { |n| n['parent'] == parent }
  withParent.map do |node|
    newNode={}
    newNode[node["_id"]]={}
    newNode[node["_id"]].merge(node["_id"] => dbCurse(withoutParent, node['_id']))
  end
end
```

which gives me a crazy mix of arrays and hashes:

```
{"globalSettings"=>[{"difficulty"=>[{"easy"=>[]}, {"normal"=>[]}, {"hard"=>[]}]}, {"terrain"=>[{"snow"=>[{"sleet"=>[]}, {"powder"=>[]}]}, {"jungle"=>[]}, {"city"=>[]}]}]}
```

I think the arrays are getting mixed in there from the #map but I'm not sure how to get rid of them to get the clean hash of hashes I show at the top of my question.

Thank you,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looking at your sample input, I'm going to make a core assumption:

The order of the hash objects in the input list are somewhat well-defined.  Namely, that if the `globalSettings` hash refers to the group `difficulty`, then the next object in the list with `_id == 'difficulty'` and `parent == 'globalSettings'` is the correct match.

If this is true, then you can write a function that accepts a description of what you're looking for (i.e., the object with `_id == 'difficulty'` and `parent == 'globalSettings'`) along with a reference to where you want that data stored, which can then recurse using deeper references.

```
def doit(obj_list, work = {})
  work.each do |key, data|
    # fetch the node
    node_i = obj_list.index { |n| n['_id'] == key && n['parent'] == data[:parent] } or next
    node = obj_list.delete_at(node_i)

    # for each group of this node, create a new hash
    # under this node's output pointer and queue it for parsing
    new_work = {}
    node['groups'].each do |group|
      data[:output][group] = {}
      new_work[group] = { parent: key, output: data[:output][group] }
    end

    # get the group data for this node
    doit(obj_list, new_work)
  end
end

input_data = JSON.parse(IO.read './input.json')
output_data = {}
doit( input_data, 'globalSettings' => { parent: nil, output: output_data } )
```

The trick here is that I'm handing the recursive call to `doit` the names of the next objects that I'm looking for from the list (using the current object's group list) and pairing each of those desired names with their parent and a reference to where I want the function to put the found data.  Each recursive call to `doit` will use deeper and deeper references into the original output hash.

Comment: Excellent!  I was focusing on primarily iterating the obj_list first.  In this approach, you focus on the work hash, which I think of as the accumulator.   Thank you.